# What difference will it make to use same class name as script name in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, robotframework

I want to use same class name in my python script as my Python script name. Also i am having only one class present in my script. For example if my script structure is mentioned below:

```
test.py
  |
  class test(object):
    def __init__(self, var1, var2 ....):
      ...
      ...
```

I want to understand what difference will it make when i import  this script and use this class from some other script ?

Comment: Nothing other than confusion because you didn't follow the PEP-8 naming convention for classes (e.g. name it `Test`).

Comment: @Martijn Pieters While writing a library for Robot framework; i have seen same name as class name and file name is being used.

Comment: The [`array` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) defines an [`array` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#array.array).

Comment: Another built-in example is class `ElementTree` in module `xml.etree.ElementTree`.

Comment: It just sounds like you wanted to follow PSR-4 convention (from PHP guys).

Comment: After doing as suggested by @MartijnPieters, you would do something like `from test import Test` or `import test` and then `test_instance = test.Test(var1, var2)`.

Comment: @iled yes...and if i use this script with robot-framework, in that case if i use robot syntax `Library test` it will import all attributes of `class test(object):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Purely from a language point of view, it won't make any difference other than it might cause a little confusion with the person importing the class.

If you use this module as a library in a robotframework test suite, then robot will automatically instantiate a class if it has the same name as the library file. The methods in that class will be exposed as the keywords from that library.

The robotframework user guide has a section titled [Creating test library class or module](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-library-class-or-module) which says (emphasis mine):

> Python classes are always inside a module. **If the name of a class
>   implementing a library is the same as the name of the module, Robot
>   Framework allows dropping the class name when importing the library.**
>   For example, class MyLib in MyLib.py file can be used as a library
>   with just name MyLib. This also works with submodules so that if, for
>   example, parent.MyLib module has class MyLib, importing it using just
>   parent.MyLib works. If the module name and class name are different,
>   libraries must be taken into use using both module and class names,
>   such as mymodule.MyLibrary or parent.submodule.MyLib.